# BJT characteristic curves, Vce vs Ic

Tags: transistors, bjt

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3BitO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

I have read several times that in a BJT transistor the variation of V<sub>CE</sub> barely influences I<sub>C</sub>.

Looking at the curve graph of a BC550 I see that for an I<sub>B</sub> of 150 μA we get about 40 mA of I<sub>C</sub> regardless of whether V<sub>CE</sub> is 6 or 12 V.

I have assembled the circuit and I have verified that keeping I<sub>B</sub> constant at 150 μA and varying V<sub>CE</sub> between 6 and 12 V, I<sub>C</sub> varies between 30 and 64 mA.

Am I misinterpreting the graph of curves?

[Edit1] I have added the schematic of the circuit that I physically assembled, on the right is my Vc vs Ic measurement table

[Edit2] I have corrected in the table the value of 2v to the correct value 12ma, typing error

Comment: The curve is given for one part with a probably unspecified hfe. If the dc gain of your part is very different [(range is from 110-800](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bc550-d.pdf), can even vary with manufacturer) you end up on a steeper curve (like the ones at 400 uA). What hfe class do you have?

Comment: For Ib 150uA and Vce=9v and Ic 50mA  the hfe = 300

Comment: @Mario Can you show us a schematic of the circuit you assembled and tell us your testing procedure?

Comment: Please _edit your question_ with the schematic, and call out the part number of the transistor.

Comment: Also mind thermal drift: the value will creep up over time, particularly at high Vce, due to temperature rise.  Preferably the measurement should be pulsed (usually < 300µs).

Comment: I have added the schematic of the circuit that I physically assembled, on the right is my Vc vs Ic measurement table

Comment: @Mario the current at 2 V Vc value was really 91 mA? It does not fit in the row. There must be a temperature rise be involved!! The Ic/Vce graph is valid for constant temperature like Tim mentioned.

Comment: @datenheim Writing error, already corrected, thanks

Comment: Also all manufacturers carefully avoid to state anything about temperature dependance of all the parameters, whuch tells me, there lurks something ;) Repeat your measurement with short pulses and longer delays and you will find something nearer to the graph. AFAIR the curves get steeper with increasing temperature.

Comment: @Mario Question: Did you really keep Ib constant? Did you consider the fact that any change in Vce acts back to Ib which, therefore, must be adjusted correspondingly?

Comment: @LvW I have a power supply with two outputs, one output for the base at a constant 1.1 volts, Ib remains constant during the test

Comment: Did you actually measure Vce, or did you just measure Vc and neglect the voltage across the 150Ω resistor?

Comment: @Theodore In the table attached to the schematic, Vc is the voltage delivered by the adjustable power supply and Ic is the collector current that flows through R2 and Q1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests I have discovered that only the two units I have of the BC550C behave in this strange way

I have subsequently tested with PN2222A and BC337 and both behave correctly as indicated by their curves

### [Edit]  New tests

I have tried with a new unit of BC550C and the result is the same, what I have discovered after many more tests is that the BC550C when we apply less than 100uA of base current the collector current fits the curve correctly but when we apply to the base more than 100uA the result is from the table that I show in the diagram

I have also proven that above 100ua when we increase Vce slightly increases the base current, this does not happen so accused with the 2N2222 or with the BC537

Comment: Do you know the manufacturer of the two misbehaving transistors? Maybe there is a small sign/icon on them?

Comment: Mario - Hi, We're getting flags as this answer isn't clear and it seems to be asking more questions. Either: (a) You correctly wrote it as an *answer*, because it really does answer your original question, and the new, implied questions are unimportant. In that case, please clearly state that this is the final solution, and come back in 2 days to "accept" this answer (or another one, if a better one has been posted by then) to close the whole topic. ([Self-answers](/help/self-answer) can only be accepted when 48 hours has elapsed since asking the question.)

Comment: [continued] Or: (b) You mistakenly wrote this as an answer, when in fact you still want more responses. In which case, this is an *update*, not an answer, and must be "edited into" your original question e.g. click "Edit" under the question, add this new information at the bottom, explain what further help is needed, then delete this "answer". *Which applies here, (a) or (b)?* Thanks. (As the OP, you would only write an answer if you solved the problem on your own and the topic can be closed.)

Comment: @datenheim No symbol appears, the complete reference is BC550C -j13, does this reference tell you something about what the manufacturer may be

Comment: @SamGibson I think it's more A than B :-), I'll accept the answer and open another question later if I get more BC550 and can perform more tests

Comment: I suggest to conduct the next experiments from higher voltage to lower, from higher current to lower.

Comment: @greybeard When I decrease Vce from 20 to 2 volts, the result is the one in the table that I show above